# Mysql RegExp select all string with matching sequence if the string is 5 character long

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySQL if a string in a column is 5 or less characters long or then select them else discard them. I may be not good in explaining them but the following scenario will explain it. I have data in column

```
Ram.
RamS.
Ram-S
Ram..
RAm.
RAmS.
Ramazan..
9R1..
9R11.
9R12.
9R13.
9R14.
9R15.
9R1Z.
9R1rA
9R1-S
9R1rAMS
9R1rR
9R1S-
9R1aA
9R1rAMS123
```

If it is 5 character long and if there is a dot then select all the corresponding values like this for value 9R1

```
9R1..
9R11.
9R12.
9R13.
9R14.
9R15.
9R1Z.
9R1rA
9R1-S
9R1rR
9R1S-
9R1aA
```

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM `ramstest`
WHERE  `Test1`
REGEXP BINARY "^9R1[A-Za-z\\.\\-]{1,2}"
```

but did not work. I will appreciate some help

Comment: What means `but did not work`?

Comment: that query returns 9 row plus it has 9R1rAMS123 kind of info as well

Comment: Use $ at the end of the regex `REGEXP BINARY "^9R1[A-Za-z\\.\\-]{1,2}$"`

Comment: You want to the distinct first 5 characters matching `9R1...`?

Comment: Yes @ R. Chappell

Comment: Thanks Jens it worked just modified the query a little bit it worked like magic thanks again.

Comment: Just for the record the query is

Comment: SELECT * FROM `ramstest`
WHERE  `Test1`
REGEXP BINARY "^9R1[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]{1,2}$"